# The meta ball isn't working in geometry nodes

Tags: geometry-nodes, metaballs

I don't know why this is happening, it should work but it doesn't. Can someone please explain why?

[image: Why are you like this. ANSWER ME]

Comment: Hello ! The Metaball type is not (yet) supported in geometry nodes, it is automatically converted to a regular mesh when it goes out of the Object Info node.

Comment: @Gorgious thank you. also if you know of a way to do something like this than please tell.

Comment: You can use a particle system